# Intro Calculus Lim Evaluation

Tags: calculus, limits

[image: The Question]

How do I simplify this to get rid of the t on the bottom for the limit? Tried doing the conjugate but cannot figure it out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**hint**: $f(t) = \dfrac{1-\sqrt{1+t}}{t\sqrt{1+t}}= -\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{1+t}\left(1+\sqrt{1+t}\right)}$ . You can now readily take the limit without worrying the "denominator" to be $0$.

Comment: I got to the first equation, how did you get the second part?

Comment: multiply top and bottom by the conjugate of the numerator and simplify.

Comment: Oh ok thanks, i'll mark it right in 4 mins.